# Can I assign a value to a variable which Sticks to this variable in every scope?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can I assign a value to a variable (int) and never lose this value inside any scope ?
the problem is I am assigning the value to the variable in some scopes but the variable returns to its default value (zero) in other scopes.. 
Example :

```
    protected void Button_AddNewCourse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ID = 10;
}
```

so when I am trying to use `ID` in other functions it falls back to zero

```
    protected void AnotherFunction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Variable ID here is zero
}
```

Comment: This question is extremely unclear. Some sample code would help enormously.

Comment: sorry for being unclear ...really I didn't know how to write it because it is too simple .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line that looks similar to this (which is probably somewhere):

```
 public int ID { get; set;}
```

to something like

```
// keep the value of ID in this page only
public int ID { get { return (int)ViewState["ID"]; } set { ViewState["ID"] = value; } }
```

or

```
// keep the value of ID in every page
public int ID { get { return (int)Session["ID"]; } set { Session["ID"] = value; } }
```

Comment: that's exactly what I am looking for ,thanks!...BUT how can I do that with a desktop application in c# (no asp.net) ?

Comment: With `public static int ID { get; set; }` and then call the variable like `SomeForm.ID`.

Answer (score 4):

At a guess, perhaps you're a newcomer to ASP.NET and haven't figured out why page-level variables don't keep their state between postbacks. Try reading up on [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) state and [Viewstate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

Or for a general overview: [ASP.NET State Management Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx)

e.g. based on your code example, you could use a Session entry to store the value:

```
protected void Button_AddNewCourse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["ID"] = 10;
}

protected void AnotherFunction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int tempID = (int)Session["ID"];
}
```

There's lots of other things you could also do - use Viewstate, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using `readonly` variables?